# Convert Thread.Join(timeLapse) to equivalent non-thread pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have the following code:

```
Thread validationThread = new Thread(DoAsyncValidationMethod);

validationThread.Start(threadParams);

bool isAborted = false;

int timeLeft = 5000;

// wait for thread terminates itself
if (!validationThread.Join(timeLeft))
{
    // timeout, abort thread
    validationThread.Abort();
    isAborted = true;
}
```

In other words, I'm doing some work that is supposed to complete in the time lapse specified (5000 ms). If completed or not, the thread approach taken will guarantee the code returns no later than 5 sec after it started.

Is there a way to accomplish this with the async/await pattern? or since the thread is just used for the trick, is there any other approach to take?

The more elegant and simple, the better.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please never ever ever call `Thread.Abort()` unless you are trying to forcibly crash out of your app. Calling abort can corrupt the state of your .NET run-time resulting in the results of **all other threads** not being reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that I used in one of my projects.

Morever, have a look at [Task.WhenAny(param Task[] task) method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194796(v=vs.110).aspx). It returns the task which is completed.

```
var timeout = 5000;
var task = Task.Run(() => {
    Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(3000, 7000));//Running time simulation!
    return "Say my name!";//Breaking Bad!
});
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {
    // Task completed within timeout.
    // What if the task is faulted or canceled.
    // I did not supply a cancellation token but it can easily be added
    // We re-await the task so that any exceptions/cancellation is rethrown.
    await task;
}
else {
    // timeout/cancellation logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you Emrah, Pretty clever the second task parameter.

Comment: @Alex, I hope it helps!. I am not sure of the performance of this code in a tight loop but I have used this without  problems so far (*'ω'*)

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - `new Random().Next(3000, 7000)` in a tight loop might be a bad idea.

Comment: @Enigmativity, It is an example to simulate a long running task. It is not a part of code. `if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {` is where the magic begins :p

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - Yes, understood, but it's not a good practice to put that in a tight loop (which you mentioned in a previous comment).

Comment: @Enigmativity, Eh? I do not understand why you would put `Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(3000, 7000));//Running time simulation!` in a loop( ･´ｰ･｀). OP is not supposed to use `Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(3000, 7000));//Running time simulation!` :)

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - Yes, I understand that. You've used it in your code and you mentioned that you are not sure about the performance of your code in a tight loop. I then commented that the use of `Random` in your code would be a problem in a tight loop. Nothing to do with the OP's code.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I should edit the answer and separate `simulation` part and `answer` part to prevent confusion.

Comment: I couldn't care less about what is inside the task in the example code. All I needed was the trick I asked for and seems I got it.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - I'm only making the comment because Stack Overflow exists to provide a library of quality questions and answers for the community first, and the poster to the question second. Future readers may see your code and assume this is good practice to use `Random` like that. It's the kind of thing that should be either avoided or an explicit note provided to clarify its use.

Comment: @Alex - I understand what you're saying, but I'm thinking about all of the other people that will read your question and the answers in the future.

Comment: @Alex, Consider marking it as answered if it helped you :) So it would help others who come across a similar problem

Comment: Why don't use the cancellation token with it's timeout?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CancellationTokenSource`. The source is a factory for `CancellationTokens`. You pass this token on to everyone you want to be able to cancel its processing in a neat way. When you want to cancel all processes that has a `CancellationToken` from the same `CancellationTokenSource`, just tell the `CancellationTokenSource` to send a cancel to all `CancellationTokens` it producted, thus cancelling all processes that have tokens from this source.

And the nice thing is, a `CancellationTokenSource` has a `CancelAfter(some timeout)`.

Its good practice, to let your process starter give you the cancellationToken, so your process starter can decide which processes it wants to cancel in one call.

```
public async Task<MyResult> MyProcessAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, ...)
{
    // do something lengthy processing, without await, regularly check if Cancellation requested
    while (stillProcessing)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ... // process
    }

    // do some processing with async-await:
    await myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Usage:

```
private async Task LengthyProcessing(...)
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    CancellationToken myCancellationToken = tokenSource.Token
    try
    {
       // Start one task, don't await yet:
       var myTask = await MyProcessAsync(myCancellationToken, ...)
       // during processing there will be regular check if cancellation requested
       // meanwhile, whenever myTask has to await, I can do some processing
       // I'll have to check for cancellation regularly also:

       while(...)
       {
           myCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
           DoSomeProcessing();
           ...
       }

       MyResult result = await myTask;
       // if here, not cancelled. can use Result:
       ProcessResult(result);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException exc)
    {
        ProcessOperationCanceled();
    }
}
```

Note that only one CancelltionTokenSource is used. Whenever this source thinks that something should be cancelled, all threads that have tokens from this source get notified about the cancellationrequest.

Instead of using exception handling via `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` consider using `bool CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`.

[MSDN how to cancel a task and its children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)

Comment: @Harald-thank you for this answer. This approach does not create a new thread, it all happens in the main thread, correct?

Comment: never mind, I looked at the code in the link and realized a task would be used in the '... // process' section in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nicely with Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive"). Then you can do this:

```
IObservable<bool> query =
    Observable.Amb(
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)).Select(_ => false),
        Observable.Start(() => DoAsyncValidationMethod()).Select(_ => true));

IDisposable subscription =
    query.Subscribe(flag =>
    {
        /* `true` succeeded, `false` timed out */
    });
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? This works just fine. What's the issue with this code?

Comment: We started using Reactive solutions in our Unity projects. A different style of thinking style but it is fun!

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - It's generally a lot more powerful than TPL.

Comment: @Enigmativity, thank you for showing me a different way.

Comment: @Enigmativity, even though I could not select your answer, I up-voted it since I wasn't aware of 'Reactive' and seems pretty interesting subject to learn more about.

Comment: @Alex - It is very good. It'd be interesting to know more about what you're trying to do as Rx is extremely powerful - what I've shown is just a very small bit of the functionality.